# Matlab: how to save TIFF with transparency or PNG with no compression?

Tags: matlab, compression, png, transparency, tiff

I have to process a lot of images and save results to image files with transparency in Matlab. But PNG compression takes too much time for me. How can I save PNG with no compression or TIFF with transparency? Are there other ways to save an image without compression and with transparency?

It's my first question here, sorry for my bad English and wrong question style if there are any mistakes in question.

Comment: "compression is too long for me" What does that mean? YOu mean it takes too much time?

Comment: @leonboy yes, that means "takes too much time" of course, thanks (fixed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [TIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiffclass.html) class in Matlab you can write TIFFs with transparancy:

```
%# create a synthetic RGBA image
ch = checkerboard(100);
rgba = repmat(ch,[1,1,4]);
rgba(:,:,4) = rgba(:,:,4)==0;
rgba = uint8(round(rgba*255));

%# create a tiff object
tob = Tiff('test.tif','w');

%# you need to set Photometric before Compression
tob.setTag('Photometric',Tiff.Photometric.RGB)
tob.setTag('Compression',Tiff.Compression.None)

%# tell the program that channel 4 is alpha
tob.setTag('ExtraSamples',Tiff.ExtraSamples.AssociatedAlpha)

%# set additional tags (you may want to use the structure
%# version of this for convenience)
tob.setTag('ImageLength',size(ch,1));
tob.setTag('ImageWidth',size(ch,2));
tob.setTag('BitsPerSample',8);
tob.setTag('RowsPerStrip',16);
tob.setTag('PlanarConfiguration',Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky);
tob.setTag('Software','MATLAB')
tob.setTag('SamplesPerPixel',4);

%# write and close the file
tob.write(rgba)
tob.close

%# open in Photoshop - see transparency!
```

Answer (score 1):

Matlab's [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) does not have parameter for the PNG compression level.  If it did, you could set it to zero for no compression.  While for TIFF it does have a `none` option for `Compression`, there is no alpha channel.  You can write to the old Sun Raster (RAS) format with an alpha channel and no compression.  Though nothing would likely be able to read it.

Comment: Using the TIFF class (but not using imwrite, apparently), you can specify that there is an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

"There is no uncompressed variant of PNG. It is possible to store uncompressed data by using only uncompressed deflate block"

The uncompressed deflate block uses a header of 5 bytes + up to 65535 bytes of uncompressed data per block.

http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Rationale.html